# Unregulated margins of html page

Tags: html, css

Something is messing with the spacing of this HTML page and it is adding extra space after the `body`. I added this `border: 2px solid #000` to `body` just to see if this extra space is included inside the body but as the image shows it isn't. I'll post the whole HTML/CSS page since it is kinda small and because I don't know where is the specific part of the code which is doing this mess.

Here is print of what I'm talking about:
[image]

HTML code:
http://pastebin.com/GrGgJEPj

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/bwv5SBjr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `.learn-more-win.slide` elements you have a `div` element with the `.container` class which has a fixed width of `970px`.

But the `.slide` has a `left-padding` of `200px` thus making the total a `1170px` and overflowing their containers.

Either remove the `200px` padding from the `.slide` or use the `.container-fluid` inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was very clear! I changed to `.container-fluid` and worked just fine.